# Undefined Symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ADAuthenticationContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated the ADAL SDK/project into my app to achieve Single sign on against AD for my customer. My app is having multiple configurations like Dev, Test, Alfa & Production, etc. Dev & Test are duplicate of Debug while rest are duplicates of Release. These configurations are specific to my app like Bundle identifier, display name, Base URL etc.

I am facing multiple issues to integrate the ADAL SDK thorough:

1: I integrated the ADAL project file to my app and embedded the framework (ADAL.framework) under Embedded binaries on my Target -> General. I could build the app when run on Dev Config. However, I receive error while tried to compile with Alfa/Production. The error is  Undefined Symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ADAuthenticationContext

2: I tried a different approach, I removed the ADAL project file from my project. I run the ADAL project alone & then copied the ADAL.framework to my project (again under embedded binaries).

In both the approaches, I could see the framework under build phases section. I run into other issues too while trying to solve this issue. Few of them are architecture related like built for x86_64 & not arm64, command ld failed with a nonzero exit code objective c, etc

Note: I tried the source code integration with Master branch. Framework integration on 2.7.11 branch.

Appreciate if you point me to thing that I am doing wrong. Also, which version is best to integrate? Should I integrate the project file or Framework that solves my issues to build against all my configurations.